# Click handler is called after attaching

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have code like this.

```
$('child').on('click', function(){ 
    ...
    $('parent').on('click', function () {
         doSomething();
    });
});
```

The problem is that parent click handler is called immediately after attaching. Probably because the click is still handling. How can I prevent this?

Comment: Why nesting handlers?

Comment: **A word of caution**: these nested event handler would keep on adding event handler on parent when clicked on child. I.e. if you have clicked twice on child, and then click on parent, then the parent click event would get fired twice.

Comment: @A.Wolff I have not so much experience with js so I am not sure that this is best solutions. A little description: on child click popup panel is showing and parent click is needed to close the panel if user click somewhere else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem Understanding:**
When the click on `child` is executed, after that the event gets propagated to its `parent`, for which you have already added the event handler during child's click. So right after child's click event handler, the parent's click event handler gets fired.

**Solution:**
The solution to stop this behaviour is to add `e.stopPropagation` first thing in child's event handler function, as:

```
$('child').on('click', function(e){ 
    e.stopPropagation;
    ...
    $('parent').on('click', function () {
        doSomething();
    });
});
```

**Demo:**
Try this @ http://jsfiddle.net/purnil/DpVGq/

Comment: each time you click on child, this add new click handler to parent. So why nesting handlers?

Comment: @A.Wolff Yes I know that nesting handlers is a bad idea, but that is not what the asker is worried about. Rather the immediate calling of parent event handler is what needed to be solved.

Comment: Correct, this was the question!

Comment: @A.Wolff see my suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Extending Punil's solution I suggest something like

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/uYTDc/)

```
$('#child').on('click', function(e){ 
  window.console && console.log("child click");
  e.stopPropagation();
  if (!$('#parent').data("clickhandler")) {
    $('#parent').data("clickhandler","already added");
    $('#parent').on('click', function(){ 
      window.console && console.log("parent clicked");
    });
  }    
  window.console && console.log("child clicked");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop the event propagating up to its parent and ancestor elements.

```
$('child').on('click', function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
```